# How do you plot a vertical line on a time series plot in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

- How do you plot a vertical line (`vlines`) in a Pandas series plot?
- I am using Pandas to plot rolling means, etc., and would like to mark important positions with a vertical line.
- Is it possible to use `vlines`, or something similar, to accomplish this?
- In this case, the x axis is `datetime`.

Answer (score 123):

```
plt.axvline(x_position)
```

It takes the standard plot formatting options (`linestlye`, `color`, ect)

[(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

If you have a reference to your `axes` object:

```
ax.axvline(x, color='k', linestyle='--')
```

Answer (score 54):

If you have a time-axis, and you have Pandas imported as pd, you can use:

```
ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2015-11-01'), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
```

For multiple lines:

```
xposition = [pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31')]
for xc in xposition:
    ax.axvline(x=xc, color='k', linestyle='-')
```

Comment: Also, if you have grouped your data, your time-axis might be in periods. e.g. if you have grouped to months: 
`xposition = [pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01').to_period(freq='M'), pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31').to_period(freq='M')]`

Answer (score 19):

DataFrame plot function returns `AxesSubplot` object and on it, you can add as many lines as you want. Take a look at the code sample below:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("2019-07-01", "2019-07-31"))  # for sample data only
df["y"] = np.logspace(0, 1, num=len(df))  # for sample data only

ax = df.plot()
# you can add here as many lines as you want
ax.axhline(6, color="red", linestyle="--")
ax.axvline("2019-07-24", color="red", linestyle="--")
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

## [`matplotlib.pyplot.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html)

- For a time series, **the dates for the axis must be proper datetime objects**, not strings.

  - Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert columns to `datetime` dtype.
- Allows for single or multiple locations
- `ymin` & `ymax` are specified as a specific y-value, not as a percent of `ylim`
- If referencing `axes` with something like `fig, axes = plt.subplots()`, then change `plt.xlines` to `axes.xlines`
- Also see [How to draw vertical lines on a given plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24988448/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Imports and Sample Data

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns  # if using seaborn

# configure synthetic dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.bdate_range(datetime(2020, 6, 8), freq='1d', periods=500).tolist())
df['v'] = np.logspace(0, 1, num=len(df))

# display(df.head())
                   v
2020-06-08  1.000000
2020-06-09  1.004625
2020-06-10  1.009272
2020-06-11  1.013939
2020-06-12  1.018629
```

### Make the initial plot

#### Using [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax.plot('v', data=df, label='v')
ax.set(xlabel='date', ylabel='v')
```

#### Using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
ax = df.plot(ylabel='v', figsize=(9, 6))
```

#### Using [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
sns.lineplot(data=df, ax=ax)
ax.set(ylabel='v')
```

### Add the vertical lines

- This should follow any of the 3 methods used to make the plot

```py
y_min = df.v.min()
y_max = df.v.max()

# add x-positions as a list of date strings
ax.vlines(x=['2020-07-14', '2021-07-14'], ymin=y_min, ymax=y_max, colors='purple', ls='--', lw=2, label='vline_multiple')

# add x-positions as a datetime
ax.vlines(x=datetime(2020, 12, 25), ymin=4, ymax=9, colors='green', ls=':', lw=2, label='vline_single')

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc="center left")
plt.show()
```

[image]