# How to draw vertical lines on a given plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Given a plot of a signal in time representation, how can I draw lines marking the corresponding time index?

Specifically, given a signal plot with a time index ranging from 0 to 2.6 (seconds), I want to draw vertical red lines indicating the corresponding time index for the list `[0.22058956, 0.33088437, 2.20589566]`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 728, accepted):

The standard way to add vertical lines that will cover your entire plot window without you having to specify their actual height is `plt.axvline`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axvline(x=0.22058956)
plt.axvline(x=0.33088437)
plt.axvline(x=2.20589566)
```

OR

```
xcoords = [0.22058956, 0.33088437, 2.20589566]
for xc in xcoords:
    plt.axvline(x=xc)
```

You can use many of the keywords available for other plot commands (e.g. `color`, `linestyle`, `linewidth` ...).  You can pass in keyword arguments `ymin` and `ymax` if you like in axes corrdinates (e.g. `ymin=0.25`, `ymax=0.75` will cover the middle half of the plot).  There are corresponding functions for horizontal lines (`axhline`) and rectangles (`axvspan`).

Answer (score 179):

### [`matplotlib.pyplot.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html) vs. [`matplotlib.pyplot.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html)

- These methods are applicable to plots generated with seaborn and `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, which both use `matplotlib`.
- The difference is that `vlines` accepts one or more locations for `x`, while `axvline` permits one location.

  - Single location: `x=37`.
  - Multiple locations: `x=[37, 38, 39]`.
- `vlines` takes `ymin` and `ymax` as a position on the y-axis, while `axvline` takes `ymin` and `ymax` as a percentage of the y-axis range.

  - When passing multiple lines to `vlines`, pass a `list` to `ymin` and `ymax`.
- Also [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html) and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) for the object-oriented API.

  - If you're plotting a figure with something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then replace `plt.vlines` or `plt.axvline` with `ax.vlines` or `ax.axvline`, respectively.
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040003/7758804) for horizontal lines with [`.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.linspace(1, 21, 200)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

# only one line may be specified; full height
plt.axvline(x=36, color='b', label='axvline - full height')

# only one line may be specified; ymin & ymax specified as a percentage of y-range
plt.axvline(x=36.25, ymin=0.05, ymax=0.95, color='b', label='axvline - % of full height')

# multiple lines all full height
plt.vlines(x=[37, 37.25, 37.5], ymin=0, ymax=len(xs), colors='purple', ls='--', lw=2, label='vline_multiple - full height')

# multiple lines with varying ymin and ymax
plt.vlines(x=[38, 38.25, 38.5], ymin=[0, 25, 75], ymax=[200, 175, 150], colors='teal', ls='--', lw=2, label='vline_multiple - partial height')

# single vline with full ymin and ymax
plt.vlines(x=39, ymin=0, ymax=len(xs), colors='green', ls=':', lw=2, label='vline_single - full height')

# single vline with specific ymin and ymax
plt.vlines(x=39.25, ymin=25, ymax=150, colors='green', ls=':', lw=2, label='vline_single - partial height')

# place the legend outside
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Seaborn [axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots) plot

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

# x index for max y values for stim and cue
c_max, s_max = fmri.pivot_table(index='timepoint', columns='event', values='signal', aggfunc='mean').idxmax()

# plot
g = sns.lineplot(data=fmri, x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event")

# y min and max
ymin, ymax = g.get_ylim()

# vertical lines
g.vlines(x=[c_max, s_max], ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, colors=['tab:orange', 'tab:blue'], ls='--', lw=2)
```

[image]

### Seaborn [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-functions-own-their-figure) plot

- Each axes must be iterated through.

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

# used to get the index values (x) for max y for each event in each region
fpt = fmri.pivot_table(index=['region', 'timepoint'], columns='event', values='signal', aggfunc='mean')

# plot
g = sns.relplot(data=fmri, x="timepoint", y="signal", col="region", hue="event", kind="line")

# iterate through the axes
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    # get y min and max
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    # extract the region from the title for use in selecting the index of fpt
    region = ax.get_title().split(' = ')[1]
    # get x values for max event
    c_max, s_max = fpt.loc[region].idxmax()
    # add vertical lines
    ax.vlines(x=[c_max, s_max], ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, colors=['tab:orange', 'tab:blue'], ls='--', lw=2, alpha=0.5)
```

- For `'region = frontal'` the maximum value of both events occurs at `5`.

[image]

### Barplot

- Bar plots have a categorical independent axis, so the tick locations have a [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Index_origin) index, regardless of the axis tick labels.

  - Select `x` based on the bar index, not the tick label. `ax.get_xticklabels()` will show the locations and labels.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load data
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# histogram
ax = tips.plot(kind='hist', y='total_bill', bins=30, ec='k', title='Histogram with Vertical Line')
_ = ax.vlines(x=16.5, ymin=0, ymax=30, colors='r')

# barplot
ax = tips.loc[5:25, ['total_bill', 'tip']].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 4), title='Barplot with Vertical Lines', rot=0)
_ = ax.vlines(x=[0, 17], ymin=0, ymax=45, colors='r')
```

[image]

### Histograms

- Histograms have a continues independent axis.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load data
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# histogram from pandas, pyplot, or seaborn 
ax = tips.plot(kind='hist', y='total_bill', bins=30, ec='k', title='Histogram with Vertical Line')
_ = ax.vlines(x=16.5, ymin=0, ymax=30, colors='r')
```

[image]

### Time Series Axis

- The dates in the dataframe to be the x-axis must be a `datetime dtype`. If the column or index is not the correct type, it must be converted with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

  - If an array or list of dates is being used, refer to [Converting numpy array of strings to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52654607/7758804)  or [Convert datetime list into date python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41387503/7758804), respectively.
- `x` will accept a date like `'2020-09-24'` or `datetime(2020, 9, 2)`.

```py
import pandas_datareader as web  # conda or pip install this; not part of pandas
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# get test data; this data is downloaded with the Date column in the index as a datetime dtype
df = web.DataReader('^gspc', data_source='yahoo', start='2020-09-01', end='2020-09-28').iloc[:, :2]

# display(df.head(2))
                   High          Low
Date                                
2020-09-01  3528.030029  3494.600098
2020-09-02  3588.110107  3535.229980

# plot dataframe; the index is a datetime index
ax = df.plot(figsize=(9, 6), title='S&P 500', ylabel='Price')

# add vertical lines
ax.vlines(x=[datetime(2020, 9, 2), '2020-09-24'], ymin=3200, ymax=3600, color='r', label='test lines')

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 91):

For multiple lines

```
xposition = [0.3, 0.4, 0.45]
for xc in xposition:
    plt.axvline(x=xc, color='k', linestyle='--')
```

Answer (score 56):

To add a `legend` and/or `colors` to some vertical lines, then use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x coordinates for the lines
xcoords = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
# colors for the lines
colors = ['r','k','b']

for xc,c in zip(xcoords,colors):
    plt.axvline(x=xc, label='line at x = {}'.format(xc), c=c)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

#### Results

[image: My amazing plot seralouk]

Answer (score 30):

Calling axvline in a loop, as others have suggested, works, but it can be inconvenient because

1. Each line is a separate plot object, which causes things to be very slow when you have many lines.
2. When you create the legend each line has a new entry, which may not be what you want.

Instead, you can use the following convenience functions which create all the lines as a single plot object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def axhlines(ys, ax=None, lims=None, **plot_kwargs):
    """
    Draw horizontal lines across plot
    :param ys: A scalar, list, or 1D array of vertical offsets
    :param ax: The axis (or none to use gca)
    :param lims: Optionally the (xmin, xmax) of the lines
    :param plot_kwargs: Keyword arguments to be passed to plot
    :return: The plot object corresponding to the lines.
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ys = np.array((ys, ) if np.isscalar(ys) else ys, copy=False)
    if lims is None:
        lims = ax.get_xlim()
    y_points = np.repeat(ys[:, None], repeats=3, axis=1).flatten()
    x_points = np.repeat(np.array(lims + (np.nan, ))[None, :], repeats=len(ys), axis=0).flatten()
    plot = ax.plot(x_points, y_points, scalex = False, **plot_kwargs)
    return plot


def axvlines(xs, ax=None, lims=None, **plot_kwargs):
    """
    Draw vertical lines on plot
    :param xs: A scalar, list, or 1D array of horizontal offsets
    :param ax: The axis (or none to use gca)
    :param lims: Optionally the (ymin, ymax) of the lines
    :param plot_kwargs: Keyword arguments to be passed to plot
    :return: The plot object corresponding to the lines.
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    xs = np.array((xs, ) if np.isscalar(xs) else xs, copy=False)
    if lims is None:
        lims = ax.get_ylim()
    x_points = np.repeat(xs[:, None], repeats=3, axis=1).flatten()
    y_points = np.repeat(np.array(lims + (np.nan, ))[None, :], repeats=len(xs), axis=0).flatten()
    plot = ax.plot(x_points, y_points, scaley = False, **plot_kwargs)
    return plot
```

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the `plt.axvline` and `plt.plot((x1, x2), (y1, y2))` *or* `plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])` as provided in the answers above, one can also use

```
plt.vlines(x_pos, ymin=y1, ymax=y2)
```

to plot a vertical line at `x_pos` spanning from `y1` to `y2` where the values `y1` and `y2` are in absolute data coordinates.