# How to add a vertical line to a seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pointplot

I want to add a vertical line in `sns.pointplot()`, which has datetime xticks, I used `ax.axvline`, but the position of the line was wrong.

my dataframe like this:

| city | year | PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 2011 | 2 |
| c1 | 2012 | 2 |
| c1 | 2013 | 3 |
| c2 | 2011 | 3 |
| c2 | 2012 | 2 |
| c2 | 2013 | 3 |

my code like this:

```
df['year']=pd.to_datetime(df['year'])

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

g=sns.pointplot(x='year',
          y='PM',
          data=df,
          ax=ax,
          color='black',
          scale=0.5,
          capsize=0.2,
          errwidth=0.8
          )


ax.axvline(x=pd.Timestamp('2012-09-01 00:00:00'),
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
        #c="red",
        ls='--',
        linewidth=0.8,zorder=0, clip_on=False)
```

[image: I got this:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`seaborn.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) is 0 indexed like a bar plot. The ticks are not a datetime range like a line plot.

  - `g.get_xticklabels() → [Text(0, 0, '2011-01-01'), Text(1, 0, '2012-01-01'), Text(2, 0, '2013-01-01')]`
  - `g.get_xticks() → array([0, 1, 2])`
- Add the vertical line based on the tick location plus the fraction of days per year. In this case, `2012` is at tick `1`, so `x=1 + 244days/365days` or `x=1.67`

  - [SO: How to calculate number of days between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151211/7758804)

    - `(datetime.date(2012, 9, 1) - datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)).days → 244`
  - [How many days between two dates](https://www.weeksuntil.com/daysbetween/)
- Also see [How to draw vertical lines on a given plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035939/7758804) for additional information about adding vertical lines to a bar plot.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'city': ['c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2'], 'year': [2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2013], 'PM': [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert to datetime if desired
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y').dt.date

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

g = sns.pointplot(x='year', y='PM', data=df, color='black', scale=0.5, capsize=0.2, errwidth=0.8, ax=ax)

g.axvline(x=1 + 244/365,
          ymin=0, ymax=1, c="red", ls='--', linewidth=0.8, zorder=0, clip_on=False)
```

[image]