# How do I connect categorical scatter points with a vertical line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have data in dataframe about different assets - let's say A,B,C,D.
What I would like to do is create a chart that looks something like this:
[image]

These assets are at a maximum of price n (let's say in our case 3.5), the dotted line and dotted circle show the historic minimum. Furthermore, it is possible to also display a range using 2 dotted circles (i.e. full circle would mean that this is the current maximum, and the range between two dotted circles indicates the range of the price in a given timeframe). I have all the data in `df`, but I would like to know whether you know how to display this either in `matplotlib` or `seaborn`.
The data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3.5,2,1.5], 'B': [3.5,1.7,1.7],'C': [3.5,0.7,0.7],'D': [3.5,1.1,1.1]})
```

Comment: This is a categorical scatter plot with vertical lines [`.vlines`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035939/7758804), not a complicated bar plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw an open scatter plot using `facecolor='none'`.  And setting `facecolor=None` will get the default with the face color equal to the main `color`.

With `plt.vlines()` you can draw vertical lines between the minima and the maxima.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3.5,2,1.5], 'B': [3.5,1.7,1.7], 'C': [3.5,0.7,0.7], 'D': [3.5,1.1,1.1]})
xvals = df.columns
colors = plt.cm.Set1.colors[:len(xvals)]
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.scatter(xvals, row, color=colors, s=200, facecolor=None if ind == 0 else 'none')
plt.vlines(xvals, df.min(), df.max(), color=colors, ls='--')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot connected with vertical lines]