# How to find all the points in time series data were new lows were made?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

So I have a set of data, which is AMD stock prices and the code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

#get stock prices
start = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
d = web.DataReader('AMD', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

So know my question is, what code would be able to find out every time the stock ( so in other words `d['Adj Close']`), made a new 52 week low. So then you would be able to print the price of the stock everytime this happened. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# import packages, seed numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.seed=42
```

---

## Generate mock data

Timestamps and price data as list:

```
timestamps = ['timestamp'+str(x) for x in range(20)]
price = [np.random.normal(100,10) for _ in range(20)]
```

[Put them to a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30522778/8565438):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamps':timestamps,'price':price})
```

---

## Look for lows

Let's define `window`. Every time the code considers a datapoint, it will consider `window`-many datapoints before it (*not including itself*).

```
window=3
```

Iterate through price, checking if the current price is the lower than any of the `window`-many prices before. Save the indices of those datapoints for which this is `True`:

```
indices=[]
for index, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if index >= window:
        if all(df.loc[index,'price'] < each for each in df[index-window:index]['price'].values):
            indices.append(index)
```

Or, if you prefer [list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it):

```
indices = [index for index, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()) if index>=window and all(df.loc[index,'price'] < each for each in df[index-window:index]['price'].values)]
```

---

## Check results

Let's [plot the data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) & our findings to make sure it is right. We will [plot the lows as vertical lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213789/how-do-you-plot-a-vertical-line-on-a-time-series-plot-in-pandas) on our plot.

```
df.plot()
for index in indices:
    plt.axvline(index,c='r')
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Which is what we have expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, especially with the other question as well, you are a savior!